# Power Query Connect to Essbase Server

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Is there a way to connect to an Oracle Essbase Server using Power Query for Excel to extract data?

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-an-Oracle-database-Power-Query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

- In the POWER QUERY ribbon tab, click From Database > From Oracle
  Database.
- In the Oracle Database dialog box, in Server Name specify the Oracle Server to connect to. If a SID is required, this can be specified in the form of “ServerName/SID”.
- If you want to import data using native database query, specify your query in the SQL Statement box.
- Click OK.
- If the Oracle server requires database user credentials:

  - In the Access a Database dialog box, enter your username and    password.
  - Click Save.

Comment: I suspect this only works for the Oracle Database Server, not Oracle Essbase Server, wrt https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cb264b1-3b58-40bd-abfc-c526bdc5689b/power-query-for-hyperion-essbase?forum=powerquery